# Netsuite Suitescript close return authorization

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've been tasked with writing a script that will close Return Authorizations over x amount of days old.  To start with this, I created a saved search that will find the RA's that the script will need to close and I can access that search in the script, but that's where I've run into a wall.  I want to mimic what happens when a user clicks on the 'Close' button in the UI, but after hitting up Google, and the SuiteScript Developer and Reference Guide, I cannot find any function that might accomplish this.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Added sample code to my answer.  Hopefully it'll save you some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to 'Close' a transaction via SuiteScript, you'll need to loop through each line item and set the `isclosed` field to 'T' then save the record.  Once all line items are closed, the transaction status will changed to Closed.

**EDIT: Adding sample code**

```
var returnAuth = nlapiLoadRecord('returnauthorization', 3945733);
var lineItemCount = returnAuth.getLineItemCount('item');

for (var i = 1; i <= lineItemCount; i++) {
    returnAuth.setLineItemValue('item', 'isclosed', i, 'T');
}

nlapiSubmitRecord(returnAuth);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  With any luck, and a lot of trial and error using the Script Debugger, I may be able to figure this out.